# What is the brand of this mystery chip?

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I found this chip in the FCC filings for a pair of headphones that I have. I'm not planning any serious reverse engineering project here, but I am curious what brand this chip is (I assume getting anything more than a brand from this image is going to be pretty hopeless). As far as I can tell, it either reads "am" or "om", or potentially "WD" in the other orientation. It is very likely a DSP (used to implement noise cancelling), although I guess it could be a general purpose microcontroller.

Original picture:
[image: Original picture]

Scaled up a little:
[image: Scaled up a little]

Comment: _”that I have”_ Good, then you can open them and take a high resolution photo of it because this is a guessing game otherwise.

Comment: Is this the best photo you can come up with? A drop of water on a phone camera can zoom more than this :D. The other markings are important as well. Usually a part number can be Googled to reveal the manufacturer.

Comment: @winny I have it but I don't want to know badly enough to open them up and risk damaging them. I know this is not a good image, but I thought it might be good enough for someone who had seen chips from this company before to identify it by.

Comment: The scaled picture doesn't help at all I'm afraid :) But I think what would help is knowing the labeling on this chip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck even with the bad photo: https://ams.com/.

I just typed the letters on the logo into google and searched for a company with the same logo/font.

EDIT: Actually, I think I lied. There's no way I could see that the third character in the logo was a sideways 'S' but "AMS" was the first thing that popped into my mind as soon I saw the "AM". I must have run into them before. I think we used one of their quadrature encoder ICs in a space elevator project in university.

Comment: Okay, but what is it?

Comment: Oh, well you asked for the brand so that's what I looked for. =/ We will need a better photo because there's zero chance of reading anything on else on the chip without it.

Comment: True, OP did ask for the vendor only...

Comment: Technically correct. The best kind of correct. Best bet is to search the entire online catalog (it's not very big especially since you can rule out lots of things by application) for an IC of a similar package. The photos looks like a QFP-48 to me, but it's hard to count the pins. I found no QFP-48 ICs in the quick search I did at the most likely categories.

Comment: I could believe it having 9 pins per side; in that case, it could be the [AS3435](https://ams.com/as3435).